# javascript node.js Server with html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have a Problem with my Node.js Server. I want to host a html Document but there is one Problem with a TypeError. I cann't find the mistake. Can you help me?

```
var express   =    require("express");
var mysql     =    require('mysql');
var app       =    express();
var fs          = require("fs");

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'test',
    debug    :  false
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8',function (err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("SERVER IS NOW RUNNING AT PORT 3000........");
```

Here now the log:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.2\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" Server.js
SERVER IS NOW RUNNING AT PORT 3000........
_http_outgoing.js:430
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:430:11)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (c:\........\Server.js:21:13)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:303:13)
```

Later I want to make a MySQL Connection with Pooling.

Comment: Which is row 21 in your  server.js file?

Comment: You're not checking if `err` is set, which it probably is...

Comment: 'res.write(data);' This ist row 21.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `createReadStream` and `.pipe` to `res` but as @robertklep mentioned, you should check `if (err)` inside the `readFile` callback.

**Here is the example**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var file = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    // res.writeHead(200, {
    //     'content-type': 'text/plain'
    // });

    file.pipe(res);
});

server.listen('3000');
```

**UPDATE**

So to match your code using express, you don't have to do much:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('SERVER IS NOW RUNNING AT PORT 3000........');
});
```

Just put all your assets in the public folder and you should be good to go. To find more info about Express you can go to http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

Comment: Can you make an example for me?

Comment: @JonasWolff I updated the answer with the example. Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you very much, but i have now a new Problem. The css and jQuery mobile resources are not in the sources of the Website.

Comment: @JonasWolff I added another example using express.

Comment: I have added Code, that allows Cross Origin, because I have some pressure of time. I will check this, when the project is ready

Comment: Here you have the whole project. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Cpdp1fyJAybFNBaG8tc1M2dzA